# Visio Layer Properties not actually functioning no matter what property i select/deselect

Tags: excel, visio

i need some help or possible guidance. i made a large flowchart that outlines the whole process inside the company i work at and it has each person, and their task. it has about 200 shapes and it displays information based on a corresponding excel sheet and will display the data points accordingly using advanced data graphics. my issue is that i have assigned about 88 of those shapes to a layer and it doesn't actually allow me to do anything to that layer as far as visibility/color/locking/etc.

so my question is do any of you have any ideas on what could be wrong? comment any additional info you may need in order to answer?

I'm going to add an excel tag just because it is technically talking to it.

Comment: My initial guess would be that that these are grouped shapes and that the sub-shapes are not all on the same layer.  Have a look a the Drawing Explorer to verify.  Also, are these custom shapes or ones based on a particular stencil and template?

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith , im using custom data graphics and when i use the drawing explorer is shows a bunch of them as Custom, but on excel theyre the manual input shape. i havent created a new shape, ive only used the ones from the basic flowchart shapes. i dont know if that helps.